# Library for calculating determinants with Kronecker products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix

I need to calculate a determinant consisting of vectors, using the Kronecker product as product. As an example I would need to be able to calculate:

$\left| \begin{array}{cc}
\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right) & 0 \\
0 & \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right) \end{array} \right|=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\0\\0\end{array}\right)$

I know of libraries containing routines for tensor network calculations, but those libraries to my knowledge do not implement determinants. Doing this right will require a good amount of work, so I wanted to ask beforehand whether anybody knows of any code that implements this already.

This is pretty specialized and therefore a long shot, but I wanted to ask nonetheless before spending days implementing it myself. Any language would be acceptable (be it Mathematica or Fortran77 or anything else).

Thanks

Comment: How big? Determinants get expensive to compute very quickly.

Comment: Good point, 8x8 would be the largest I might ever need, so it should still be fast, even with expensive algorithms like the Laplace method.

Comment: Have you tried [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct.html)?

Comment: I ended up implementing a workaround for our problem using character arrays. But I wouldn't know how to implement it in mathematica, since I don't know how to make the Kronecker product the default product for the determinant in MMA. Nor do I know whether the determinant routine is implemented in such a way that it takes the non commutativity into account.